Leer archivos excel (.xlsx) en C++ en CLion?
Estoy intentado leer dos archivos excel .xlsx en c++ pero no puedo, estos son los archivos, estoy usando CLion, chat-gpt me da la opcion de usar una libreria llamada "libxl" pero no he tenido exito.


Cuál es el código?
